CORS Issue with Google Apps Script and Chrome Extension: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"
I'm developing a Chrome extension that sends a POST request to a Google Apps Script web app. However, I'm encountering the following CORS error in the browser:

Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/deployId/exec' from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here’s the relevant part of my Chrome extension code:
function postSheet() {
  console.log("a");
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["apiKey"], function (result) {
    const apiKey = result.apiKey || "";
    const googleData = {
      type: "messageUsage",
      apiKey: apiKey,
    };
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/deployId/exec";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      body: JSON.stringify(googleData),
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Google Sheet response:", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error posting to Google Sheet:", error);
      });
  });
}

Here’s the server-side code running on Google Apps Script:
function doPost(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  try {
    if (JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).apiKey) {
      var apiKey = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).apiKey;
      var customer = findRowByUniqueId(sheet, apiKey);

      return ContentService.createTextOutput(sheet.getRange(customer, 9).getValue())
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify("success"))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      .addMetaTag("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  } catch (error) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      status: 'error',
      message: error.toString()
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

What I’ve Tried
Setting CORS Headers:
I tried adding .addMetaTag("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") and setting the MIME type to JSON in the Apps Script response. It didn't work.
Using no-cors Mode:
Switching the fetch mode to no-cors avoids the error but doesn't allow me to process the JSON response.
Chrome Extension Permissions:
I’ve verified that my manifest.json has the necessary permissions, including <all_urls> and storage.
Avoiding Preflight Requests:
I attempted to simplify headers to avoid OPTIONS preflight requests but didn’t succeed.
Proxy
I also tried cors-anywhere
What I Expect
How can I correctly set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in Google Apps Script to resolve this issue? Is there a recommended approach for enabling JSON-based communication between a Chrome extension and Google Apps Script?
I want to send each message to a Google Apps Script with the person's API key and get the total number of messages from there.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Firstly I think asking several questions in one question may result in downvoting or closing the question. Consider focusing on the initial problem, the CORS and ask your remaining questions separately.
Now to the point. At a quick glance, you're using addMetaTag to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin. This adds a meta tag to the page, and not a header. Access-Control-Allow-Origin can only be set as an HTTP header. Please confirm if the response serves the required headers.

You can't set headers or handle  OPTIONS in Apps script web server. You have to avoid preflight by changing content type to text/plain or other simple types. See  linked duplicate.
